# FlashLight Not Starting on first click

Tags: android, android-camera

I made a simple FlashLight Application. It's working well, but there is a bug. When I press the down button the very first time after launching the app, it doesn't start the flashlight. When I press the button a second time, it starts the flashlight.

Help me solve this issue. Thank you!

> Issue: FlashLight not starting on very first button press.

```
private Camera camera;

private ImageButton flashlightButton;

private TextView Status;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 123;

boolean hasCameraFlash = false;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},CAMERA_REQUEST);

        Status = findViewById(R.id.Status);
        flashlightButton = findViewById(R.id.flashlight_button);

        flashlightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (hasCameraFlash){
                    if (Status.getText().toString().contains("ON")){
                        Status.setText("OFF");
                        flashlightOff();
                    } else {
                      Status.setText("ON");
                      flashlightOn();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Flash Available on your device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void flashlightOn(){
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId,true);
            flashlightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_on);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        }
    }

    private void flashlightOff(){
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            String camerid = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(camerid,false);
            flashlightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_off);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    hasCameraFlash = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied for the Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);

            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Permissions added for this App....                                                                           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>  
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

Answer (score 0):

use permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
            android:required="false" />  
      <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="false" />
```

Code:

```
 Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
            p = mCamera.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(mContext, mCamera);
            mCamera.startPreview();
```

Answer (score 0):

No errors found in your codes. Maybe in your XML layout file, the button has an attribute like:

```
android:onClick="onClick"  //delete if such line exists
```

The other probability is the button has an attribute like:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" //delete if such line exists
```

Comment: @Rakesh could you post layout XML

Comment: <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flashlight_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/flashlight_off"/>